# PHP Save nested json to mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, json

I have some json data that i am retrieving from an external url. It is not importing correctly unless i take out some of the brackets. Anyone know how to properly import this json data? I don't really need the "success", "num_items", "build time" and "updated at". Im a noobie. Thanks!

Here is the php

```
$filename = "http://www.someurl.com/data.json";
$data = file_get_contents($filename);  
$array = json_decode($data, true);

 foreach($array as $row)  
 {  
      $sql = "INSERT INTO table_all_items(name, quality) VALUES (
      '".$row["name"]."', 
      '".$row["quality"]."'
      )";       
mysqli_query($connect, $sql);
 }
```

Here is data.json

```
{
    "success": true,
    "num_items": 7312,
    "items": [
        {
            "name": "Net",
            "quality": "New"
        },
        {
            "name": "Ball",
            "quality": "New"
        },
        {
            "name": "Hoop",
            "quality": "Used"
        }
    ],
    "build_time": 320,
    "updated_at": 15680
}
```

Comment: This json data is valid. Is this the version you receive from the server, or the one you have edited ?

Comment: It is what i received from the server. It is slightly modified to make it cleaner for stack exchange. My other question was regarding apostrophes and not related.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were looping through the wrong element of your array.
As you want to list the items, your loop must look like :

```
 foreach($array["items"] as $row)  


//$filename = "http://www.someurl.com/data.json";
//$data = file_get_contents($filename);  
$data='{
    "success": true,
    "num_items": 7312,
    "items": [
        {
            "name": "Net",
            "quality": "New"
        },
        {
            "name": "Ball",
            "quality": "New"
        },
        {
            "name": "Hoop",
            "quality": "Used"
        }
    ],
    "build_time": 320,
    "updated_at": 15680
}';
$array = json_decode($data, true);
$sql = "INSERT INTO table_all_items(name, quality) VALUES ";
 foreach($array["items"] as $row)  
 {  
      $sql = $sql." (
      '".$row["name"]."', 
      '".$row["quality"]."'
      ),";       
 }  
  mysqli_query($connect, substr($sql,0,-1));
```

I also updated the sql query, for it sends only one request with many values, instead on many requests with one value.